# Why are queries executed from mysql workbench taking much longer than executing them directly from the mysql cli?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a query that does multiple joins on several tables and uses a covering index.  It seems to run a lot faster when executed directly from the mysql cli instead of from mysql workbench.

```
mysql > some query
...
250 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

from mysql workbench it takes about `~0.200 sec duration / 0.100 sec fetch`

Is there a reason beyond latency, authentication and transfer of data why it would be orders of magnitude faster on the console?  Does a three-way tcp handshake occur each time a query is executed from mysql workbench or does that tcp connection stay open until you close the workbench session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a persistent connection in Workbench, so there's no overhead in that regard. Executing a query should be equally fast in both CLI as well as Workbench, however data transfer is a bit slower sometimes because Workbench locally caches results first to be able to sort over it when the user clicks a header field in the resultset view (including multi column sort). Try repeating the query in both tools and see if the times still differ. The first run of a query is usually slower than following runs due to the execution cache.

Comment: I executed both queries several times in succession and they returned the same results every time in regards to speed.  If it was a data transfer issue, wouldn't only the "fetch" part of the time breakdown be affected? Why is the "duration" so high?

Comment: Hmm, there really should not be any difference. Not sure what's going on there. Workbench adds a limit clause if there's none (can be switched off in the preferences). Try comparing something that needs a lot more time to execute. In that scale it's hard to say if e.g. connector overhead plays a role. Only if the same difference shows up for queries running like 30 secs there's really an issue.