# MySQL Cli output file, Workbench running slower

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, percona

I'm running a basic query with following format

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE data = 'X'
```

I generally have never had any issues with Workbench but this query has seemed to get stuck? It is taking a very long time to process and I even get locked out as well. I turned my focus to the CLI and I was able to run the query and get an output fairly quickly.

```
827148 rows in set (1.88 sec)
```

I read the following topic but didn't really come up with an answer.
[Why are queries executed from mysql workbench taking much longer than executing them directly from the mysql cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757643/why-are-queries-executed-from-mysql-workbench-taking-much-longer-than-executing).

Now I generally stay away from the CLI but I can run all my queries there if I have to, the only issue I have is outputting files.

*How do I do an `INTO OUTFILE` from the CLI and direct it towards either a, a shared drive or b, to my machine?* (I'm using puTTY to connect to the server)

Server Description
Percona 68.0
MyISAM
Running on CentOS

Any information would be greatly appreciated. Thank you and I hope I've been thorough enough I've tried searching for a solution but couldn't find a solid answer.

Comment: welcome @Felix, was a good first question. (I removed that part for next readers)

Comment: 800K result rows is a lot. Do you load that completely or is there a limit set for your queries? You can set the default limit in the preferences or use a temporary limit by selecting a value from the limit drop down in the toolbar above an sql editor.

Comment: It is, anytime I add a limit it will go through a lot faster but I am being requested a pull of that many rows.