# Why does MySQL Workbench execute a query so much slower than my app?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have an app that runs a complex join and it returns in a few seconds. No big deal. But when I run that same exact query in **Workbench 8.0.12**, it takes over a minute. The connection string is identical.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757643/why-are-queries-executed-from-mysql-workbench-taking-much-longer-than-executing) doesn't help, seems to be a different issue.

My app is .NET using MySQL.Data dll. I have used Workbench many times in the past, but usually with PHP apps. From years of experience I have always seen Workbench run a query in roughly the same time as the app can run it.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    model.Code as ModelCode, 
    prod.parts_group as PartsGroup, 
    rules.id AS ID, 
    rules.Code as ConstraintName, 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(rules.statement, '''', ''), ' me.', ''), '}and ', '} and '), '}or ', '} or ') as Statement, 
    ifnull(rules.priority,5) AS Priority, 
    model.serie_id AS SeriesID
FROM 
    toy_product_constraint as rules
    INNER JOIN toy_product as prod ON rules.product_id = prod.id
    INNER JOIN toy_product_model as model ON prod.model_id = model.id
    JOIN ModelImport mi ON model.code = mi.ModelCode
WHERE
    rules.statement <> 'TRUE'
    AND rules.market_id is null
    AND rules.statement not like 'hasSDR(true)%'
    AND rules.statement like 'SPECOPTION{00%'
```

The last 3 where clauses seem to be adding 99% of the extra query time:

```
AND rules.market_id is null
AND rules.statement not like 'hasSDR(true)%'
AND rules.statement like 'SPECOPTION{00%'
```

*Without those last 3*, the query runs in 1 second in Workbench. *With those last 3* it takes over 60 seconds *in Workbench*. We could talk about indexes and other things, but the real mystery is why does this same query run (and return records) in less than 3 seconds in my app (I have stepped through the code line-by-line and verified this) and over 60 seconds in workbench??

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer: The built-in `Limit to 500 rows`, etc, seems to be REALLY slow to figure out which 500 to do. When I open it wide, it runs fast. It's a large dataset.

Comment: That limitation feature uses a simple `LIMIT x,y` clause. What happens when you do the same in your app? Does it become similarly slow? If so, the server has a problem.

Comment: I had the exact same issue.  Changed the settings under Query > Limit Rows > Don't Limit.  After that, queries that would just hang forever are now completing in reasonable time.